# Proper way to deal with both encoding and charset/ccsid through a messaging bridge?

Tags: character-encoding, spring-integration, ibm-mq, messaging

We are struggling with charset and encoding (such an original problem!)  from a message broker to another going through a messaging bridge using adapter-channel-adapter pattern (and using Spring Integration implementation).

```
[INBOUND BROKER] == || ==> [CHANNEL ADAPTER => CHANNEL => CHANNEL ADAPTER] == || ==> [OUTBOUND BROKER]
```

On either side of the bridge, we do encounter several kind of brokers (Ibm Mqseries, RabbitMq, Kafka), and some may be of various versions (MqSeries mainlay, that can go from antediluvian 6+ to modern 9+).
The brokers are also hosted on various VMs / machines, including (but not only) AS400, AIX, OpenVMS, RedHat (with different encodings)
Eventually, messages are feeded different ways; mainly through java applications, but also c/c++, and shell scripts.

We tried to cover most of the scenarii we could expect, setting up encoding/CCSID parameters when provided (from Spring Integration POV), message headers (from message provider POV), etc.
We also built several testing pipelines trying to cover as many scenarii as possible.
Despite that, we still do encounter encoding problems with unexpected combination of broker type/version, systems, charset and so.
So, we decided to rethink our problem coming back to basis : best practices.
We are trying to state what are the correct and/or most reliable (provided there is at least one) way(s) to manage both ccsid and encoding passing from a broker to another through a bridge (Spring Integration or any other one).

What we understand, so far, is that both encoding and CCSID can be set (even if it's not effective) at several points of the workflow.
Below, I will list all those places we found that a  llow to change one or both of them (we may have missed some).
As a matter of example, I will use IBMMqseries on both sides... on purpose because it involves most of the encoding problem we encounter (not because of what it is, but because it used to be the Legacy broker, thus was the most and oldest used).
Also, in the below exemple, each broker/bridge will be hosted on its own machine / VM.

My main question are thus :

- Should the CCSID and/or the encoding be managed withinthe bridge, and/or should this negotiation be leaved to brokers?
- Provided the bridge is a suited place, what is the proper way to do it : using built-in parameters (see exemple below) or use some transformers (or whatever else)?
- Is there anyway to "guess" both encoding and ccsid such a way I don't have to write them down, thus allowing to have an auto-adaptive transformation?
- And if the bridge is not the suited place : does it mean I have to configure a broker such at it does match its distant counterpart?

**some consideration** (06/12 edit)

- My POV is from a bridge side. I must provide a bridge between hundreeds of differents brokers. Thus, as a Middleware, I have little (or no!) control over the out/inbound brokers. The very little control I have is over basic configuration (eg. ccsid setting in their Queue Manager)
- If your best practice does not involve the bridge side, I am interested anyway. (I may not be able to apply it, but this would at least be a piece of information I could take into consideration)

**Places where ccsid / encoding can be set (and sometimes changed) during the message lifecycle**

```
---------- INPUT MACHINE / VM ------------------

SYSTEM : ENCODING (will not be changed)  
MANAGER IN : CCSID (can be changed in configuration)  
PRODUCER IN (eg java application) : CCSID : default UTF-8. Could be changed, but not easilly (some input modules are so old that they their maintaineras have already retired)

---------- BRIDGE -----------
inbound queue object : ccsid AND encoding  
inbound queue object : receiveCCSID (in combination with receiveConversion)  
outbound queue object : ccsid AND encoding  
outbound queue object : receiveCCSID (in combination with receiveConversion) (but doc sounds like it has no effect... though we may have misunderstood it)    

---------- OUTPUT MACHINE / VM ------------------

SYSTEM : ENCODING (will not be changed)  
MANAGER OUT: CCSID (can be changed in configuration)
```

**bridge main conf** (matching the above example) :

```
    <bean id="jmsQueueIn" class="om.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="someJmsConnectionFactory">
        <property name="encoding" value="273"></property> #NATIVE
        <property name="CCSID" value="819"></property>  
        <property name="receiveCCSID" value="297"></property>   #FRENCH
        <property name="receiveConversion" value="2"></property>    
        <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="QM1" />
        <property name="baseQueueName" value="QUEUE.IN" />
        <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
        <property name="MQMDMessageContext" value="2"></property>
        <property name="MQMDReadEnabled" value="true"></property>
        ...
    </bean>
    <bean id="someListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" >
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryCaching" />
        <property name="destination" ref="jmsQueueIn" />
        ...
    </bean>
    
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
        container="someListener"  
        id="adapterIn" 
        channel="someChannel"
        .../>


    <bean id="jmsQueueOut" class="om.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="someJmsConnectionFactory">
        <property name="encoding" value="546"></property> # REVERSED
        <property name="CCSID" value="297"></property>  
        <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="QM2" />
        <property name="baseQueueName" value="QUEUE.OUT" />
        <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
        <property name="MQMDMessageContext" value="2"></property>
        <property name="MQMDReadEnabled" value="true"></property>
        ...
    </bean>
    
    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
            channel="someChannel" 
            id="adapterOut" 
            destination="jmsQueueOut" 
            connection-factory="someConnectionFactoryCaching" 
            .../>
```

Comment: Why cannot you transfer data in `byte[]` and just don't care about charsets and encoding?

Comment: Mainly because I am on the bridge side, and as a Middleware have little control over the inbound and outbound brokers (there may be hundreds of them).  The best I can do is ask them to change their broker's CCSID... provided it's a solution (I should have specified it : will add it in the POST). Anyway if you say this is a "best practice", It's a legitimate answer, thus am interested in it

Comment: I don't think you can support every possible message format of every possible software; support exactly one format: unparsed, unconverted, uninterpreted raw binary data.